# Using check boxes to filter list box of worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets. I create a list box on a user form with these worksheets in alphabetical order, click on the line and hit print.

I would like to check a box and hit search and have only the filtered worksheets appear.

User Form
[image]

Worksheet tabs
[image]

```vb
Dim i As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ListBox1.Clear
    SE = False
    TE = False
    SS = False
    TS = False
    AK = False
    EK = False
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub FilterButton1_Click()
    
    If SE = True Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        Next i
    End If
    If TE = True Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "*TE*"
    Next i
    End If
    If SS = True Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "*SS*"
    Next i
    End If
    If TS = True Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "*TS*"
    Next i
    End If
    If AK = True Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "*AK*"
    Next i
    End If
    If EK = True Then
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ListBox1.AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "*EK*"
    Next i
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Are those checkboxes also the names of your worksheets?

Comment: It would be easier to modify your existing code, but you haven't included it...  At least post the code you use to fill the listbox.

Comment: The worksheet tabs contain the "SE" or "TE" etc. I was hoping to use wild cards in the filter.

Comment: The "SE" checkbox line is the one that works but show all the worksheet tabs.

Comment: I think you'll need to add some more detail to this question (especially around what you expect your lines of code to do and what you're actually seeing it do). I don't understand what the lines you've posted are trying to do  - so there's a chance other contributors will be equally confused. Could you also let us know if this code even compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial form load calls `LoadSheetList` with no argument, so all sheets will be loaded.

Your "Filter" button calls `LoadSheetList True` which will only add sheets based on the checkbox statuses.

```vb
Sub LoadSheetList(Optional filtered As Boolean = False)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, nm
    
    ListBox1.Clear 'first remove all items
    'loop all sheets
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        nm = ws.Name
        If Not filtered Or (filtered And SheetOK(nm)) Then
            ListBox1.AddItem nm 'add if included or not filtering
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

'review checkbox status to see is a sheet with the provided name should be added
'EDIT: updated to "and" checkboxes, not "or"
Function SheetOK(sheetName) As Boolean
    Dim cb, rv as Boolean

    rv = False 'default result
    For Each cb In Array(SE, TE, SS, TS, AK, EK)
        If cb.Value = True then
            if not sheetName Like "* " & cb.Name & "*" then
                rv = False
                Exit For
            Else
                rv = True
            End If
        End If
        SheetOK = rv
    Next cb
    
End Function
```

Comment: I can't wait to try it. It looks like it is exactly what I needed. I will keep you posted. Thank you!

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECTLY,
Thank you again for your help Tim

Comment: Sorry to bother.
After using the form and it is totally usable the way it is but, here's the part I'm sorry for.
When I filter with more than one checkbox, it filters all the worksheets with the right information but it would work better if it filtered by (selection 1 "&" selection 2.....).
I am going to try and figure it out but will accept any help.

Comment: See my edit - untested but i think that should work